# Convert Nodejs API to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created a NodeJS project where I have saved the data in a file data.js. It is saved in a server in a local host and I can use it as an API call.
Now I would like to convert this project using MongoDB as the backend to make it more dynamic. I have fetched data using React Hooks in the HomeScreen Page.

Do I need to change the React Hook and Fetching data(axios) Code??

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change your React code if you ensure your Nodejs API still provides same data in same format as before. Just need to update backend nodejs code to store and fetch details from mongodb instead of the data.js file.

Comment: I am using fetching it as a map.

Comment: Yes that is fine just make sure your nodejs  API is still the same as before adding mongodb.
From: React --> Nodejs API --> data.js
To:     React --> Nodejs API --> mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Just Use `MongoDB Queries` to fetch details and send it in the response like as you were sending before from `data.js`. The difference would be now is you will be storing your data in `MongoDB collections` and read it from `collections` according to your requirements.